# Jqplot - Highlighter show tool tip with data from multiple y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, graph, jqplot

I am using JqPlot.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/yRLJF/) and below is my screenshot. I am using two y axis. On the left y axis I have my revenue and on my right y axis I have my page views.

Now on hover on the lines, I want to show both the Views and Revenue in the tooltip, as seen in the example below I am only able to get data from 2 axes at a time.

Any thoughts ?

[image]

Below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

  s1 = [['23-May-08',1, 11],['24-May-08',4, 14],['25-May-08',2, 22],['26-May-08', 6, 26]];
  s2 = [['23-May-08',11, 1],['24-May-08',14, 4],['25-May-08',22, 2],['26-May-08', 26, 6]];

  plot1 = $.jqplot('chart',[s1, s2],{
     title: 'Highlighting, Dragging, Cursor and Trend Line',
     axes: {
         xaxis: {
             renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
             tickOptions: {
                 formatString: '%#m/%#d/%y'
             },
             numberTicks: 4
         },
         yaxis: {
             tickOptions: {
                 formatString: '$%.2f'
             }
         }
     },
     highlighter: {
         show:true,
     },
     cursor: {
         show: true
     },
      series: [
        {
            lineWidth: 2,
            highlighter: { formatString: "<div style='background-color:white; border:1px #ddd solid; width:220px; height:60px'>%s . Views : %s Revenue : %s </div>" }
        },
        {
            yaxis: 'y2axis',
            highlighter: { formatString: "<div style='background-color:white; border:1px #ddd solid; width:220px; height:60px'>%s . Views : %s Revenue : %s </div>" }
        }]
  });
});​
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I did, I used the `tooltipContentEditor` property of `highlighter`. Check out the [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/yRLJF/2/).

[image]

```
series: [
{
    lineWidth: 2,
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        tooltipContentEditor: function (str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {

            var date = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][0];
            var revenue = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][3];
            var views = plot.data[1][pointIndex][4];

            var html = "<div>Date : ";
            html += date;
            html += "  <br>Money : ";
            html += revenue;
            html += "  <br>Views : ";
            html += views;
            html += "  </div>";

            return html;
        }
    }
},
{
    yaxis: 'y2axis',
    highlighter: {
        show: true,
        tooltipContentEditor: function (str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {

            var date = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][0];
            var views = plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex][5];
            var revenue = plot.data[0][pointIndex][6];

            var html = "<div>Date : ";
            html += date;
            html += "  <br>Money : ";
            html += revenue;
            html += "  <br>Views : ";
            html += views;
            html += "  </div>";

            return html;
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: You can format or hide grid from yaxes2 if you want => `y2axis:{tickOptions:{showGridline: false}}`

Answer (score 1):

In place of

```
plot.data[seriesIndex][pointIndex]
```

use this

```
plot.series[seriesIndex].data[pointIndex]
```

because plot.data holds the user specified data (which may be unsorted)

and plot.series holds the plotted data (which may be sorted if sortdata is true which is default).